# How to not trigger afterTagAdded on loading pre-added elements via Ajax with Tag-it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

So this is my case - on clicking one button i load

```
<ul id="members">
      <li>member1</li>
      <li>member2</li>
</ul>
```

(the ul goes inside the .modal-body) via ajax, filled with pre-added list elements and after that Im loading this Jquery plugin Tag-it! on the ul :

```
$.post('/profil/ajax-load-group/', params, function(data) {         
    $('#sidebar_modal .modal-body').html(data);
    $('#members').tagit({               
    allowDuplicates: false,
    afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        members = added_members + ui.tagLabel + ';';
    }
```

})

So the problem is that it catches the pre-added elements as they are added after the plugin loads and im struggling to find a way around that, cause i really need to find the members, who are added after that, not the one which are in the datebase already.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by uniquely classifying the li elements that already exist.

```
<ul id="members">
 <li class='exists'>member1</li>
 <li class='exists'>member2</li>
</ul>
```

and then check for that in the afterTagAdded function callback

```
$.post('/profil/ajax-load-group/', params, function(data) {         
    $('#sidebar_modal .modal-body').html(data);
    $('#members').tagit({               
    allowDuplicates: false,
    afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        if($(ui.tag).hasClass('exists'))
             return false;
        members = added_members + ui.tagLabel + ';';
    }               
})
```

Now when you add new li elements with the caveat that they are added without class='exists' attribute, tagit it should work as expected.

Hope this helps!